# Moat Lurker: Mechanic Question

Tags: hearthstone

Suppose I use a Moat Lurker to remove a card that is, at the moment, annoying me. Something like "The Lich King".

What happens if I then play a card that takes this Moat Lurker off the board? Like say, Shadowstep, Vanish, or Sap, or other effects like Youthful Brewmaster that remove a card and return it to the hand?

Then I could play Moat Lurker on another card to destroy it, will Moat Lurker return both this second target AND The Lich King, or only the second target?

If this is indeed true, it could be pretty powerful in deck that can reliably return moat lurker to the hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use moat lurker to kill something and then return the moat lurker to your hand before it dies, the thing you killed is gone forever because the deathrattle didn't trigger. It is a legit strategy to use moat lurkers with things like shadowstep and brewmasters for easy removal

Comment: Or silence it to remove the deathrattle effect.

Comment: or evolve! I currently run moat lurker in my shaman.

Comment: Have you tested this? Because I actually saw this happen, where the moat lurker was played a second time, and BOTH destroyed minions popped back out when the moat lurker was destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

As Arin stated, if you return the moat lurker to your hand, it basically *resets* it's history, or, in other words - forgets that it killed the Lich King. This is a viable method to use shadowstep or youthful brewmaster, or ancient brewmaster on your moat lurker.

This is **not** the only way to make moat lurker an effective removal card, however. You can also use priest silence or any other battlecry-silencing minion such as Ironbeak Owl or Spellbreaker.